# SSMS Object Explorer Attempt to expand Tables->Keys node throws "Failed to retrieve data for this request" to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms-2014

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.2000.8, attempts to expand various nodes in Object Explorer (such as the `Tables->Keys` and `Programmability->Types->User-Defined Table Types`) result in the exception
    `"Failed to retrieve data for this request. unknown property IsMemoryOptimized"`; but only for Azure SQL Database V12 instances. For the same database in an on-premises SS2014CU5 instance, these nodes do expand without throwing this exception.

Comment: Update SSMS or download latest version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this with the September 2015 Preview version of SSMS which could be found at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

and was able to expand Tables->Keys and Programmability->Types->User-Defined Table Types